# TYPO3 page does not get cached

Tags: caching, typo3

I have some 4.5.6 installation of TYPO3 and a quite old, modified tt_news extension running.

My client noticed that the indexed search is not working for the news pages anymore.
So i checked, and as I thought the cache entries for the detail pages are not created anymore.
Actually only one cache entry is created, containing the html of the first detail page I requested (through the frontend). 
I enabled the adminPanel and it also shows me that no_cache = 1. Why is that? My URL looks like this:

```
www.mypage.com?id=231&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=2457&tx_ttnews[backPid]=&tx_ttnews[swords]=&cHash=287ca316c98761c2dff769a7d3c6b587
```

Anyone can help me with that?[image]

Comment: Seems like the cHash which is generated, is not valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to realUrl. We updated to a new version, and then caching worked again. Looks like realUrl generated invalid cHashes...

Answer (score 6):

There are several places to disable the TYPO3 page cache.

a) It can be set by TypoScript using

```
config.no_cache = 1
```

or

```
page.config.no_cache =1
```

Check in the TypoScript Object Browser if it is set on this page and check how it is set.

b) It can be set in the page properties.

c) It can be set in an extension. If e.g. your customized version of tt_news contains this code

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache()
```

the cache for all pages containing the plugin is disabled.

Furthermore the plugin can be made running as a USER_INT like this

```
$this->pi_USER_INT_obj = 1;
```

If this is set, then the content of this plugin is not checked. E.g. on the page you opened the admin panel, you have three USER_INT objects. But this is not the problem since you have set "no_cache" which means that the cache for the whole page is disabled.